# OK to omit "exit 0" at end of Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, exit-code

On Ubuntu 14's Ruby 1.9.3, when I run the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

and the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
exit 0
```

they do the same thing.  In particular, a subsequent `echo $?` prints `0`.  How universal is this behavior?  Can I safely omit `exit 0` from the end of a nontrivial script?

Comment: yeah, you don't need the explicit `exit 0` at the end of the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Universally in UNIX, 0 is reserved for success and codes other than 0 - different sorts of errors.

In any normal language, unless your program throws some sort of exception or explicitly exits with a different code, you can safely assume that it exited with 0.

---

As per the [documentation of `Process#exit`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Process.html#method-c-exit):

> exit(status=true)
>   [...]The optional parameter is used to return a status code to the invoking environment. true and FALSE of status means success and failure respectively.
>   The interpretation of other integer values are system dependent.

Meaning Ruby exits with success by default, whatever success means for the underlying system.

As per the documentation of [exit codes from The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html):

> [...] A successful command returns a 0, while an unsuccessful one returns a non-zero value that usually can be interpreted as an error code. Well-behaved UNIX commands, programs, and utilities return a 0 exit code upon successful completion, though there are some exceptions. [...]

Meaning you are will get 0 in a UNIX environments.

As per [Microsoft's documentation on exit codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382.aspx):

> ERROR_SUCCESS
>   0 (0x0)
>   The operation completed successfully.

Meaning you will also get zero in Windows.

Comment: The convention is familiar.  I hope that the answer is yes.  But I'm hoping for stronger proof.  (Who said that Ruby is "normal"?)

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, the answer is definitely yes. It is normal in that sense. As Ruby doesn't have official documentation I'm not sure what proof you want. Link to the exact line in the implementation that exists with 0 by default?

Comment: Proof: either a statement in e.g. http://ruby-doc.org/ or, yes, a line in the source code.  At least something more than "it works on my computer too," more than "because I say so."

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, added links to various documentations.

Comment: As for code documentation, the exit status in MRI Ruby is mostly determined by [`ruby_cleanup`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2aaca105058950af2fc1a39c7e5c7cb032c85fff/eval.c#L148-L231) which in turn is called by [`ruby_stop`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/2aaca105058950af2fc1a39c7e5c7cb032c85fff/eval.c#L252-L257) which is the primary way the Ruby VM is shutdown. Note that there are other ways to kill a process than a regular shutdown (e.g. by sending it a signal). In that case, the termination status will be different.

Comment: Thank you, @ndn.  But Process#exit's doc does *not* claim that "Ruby exits with success by default."  And that is exactly my question.  *Does* a Ruby script exit with a status code that means success, when it lacks an `exit` command?  Equivalently, from that doc's "click to toggle source": does a script without an `exit` command always exit by calling `rb_f_exit()`?  That function's source code is clear enough.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, it does say that it's the default, look at the default value for the status parameter - `exit(status=true)`.

Comment: (move to talk?)  @ndn, yes, true is the default for `exit()`.  No, it doesn't say what happens when the script *lacks* an `exit()`.  That's the case in question.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, fair point. Lets look at it another way - the documentation says that it respects the underlying system's integer exit codes. So unless you are speculating that the default semantic isn't that a Ruby program runs successfully unless something exceptional happens, there is no reason to suggest you will not get 0 under UNIX or Windows given normal execution.

Comment: I don't think you will find something more black and white in the documentation and I don't intend to spend my evening code spelunking in MRI for something I'm 100% certain of. Still, if you want to go that route, Holger's comment provides a good starting point.